# How to set a fixed height for a JavaFX text field regardless of its contents?

Tags: java, javafx, textfield

I'm making a notepad application using JavaFX which includes a font selector window. The font selector includes a textfield within a gridpane layout which functions as a sample of what the selected font options will look like.

Font selector:
[image: font selector]

However, if the font chosen is taller than the text field, the field stretches to fit the text, distorting the window.

Distorted font selector:
[image: distorted font selector]

I want the sample textfield to remain the same size even if the text contained is taller than the field, like the font selector shown below:
[image: font selector]

I've tried using the 'setPrefSize' and 'setMaxSize' textfield methods to force a maximum height.

```
public static final String display(String savedFamily, String savedStyle, String savedSize, String stylesheet) {

    fontFamily = savedFamily;
    fontSize = savedSize.substring(0, savedSize.length() - 2);
    fontWeight = getChosenWeight(savedStyle);
    fontStyle = getChosenStyle(savedStyle);

    // Add stage
    Stage window = new Stage();
    window.initModality(Modality.APPLICATION_MODAL);

    TextField sample = new TextField("AaBbYyZz");
    sample.setEditable(false);
    sample.getStyleClass().add("sample");
    sample.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
    sample.setStyle(getCSS());
    sample.setPrefSize(200, 60);
    sample.setMaxHeight(60);

    // Add list view title labels
    Label fontLabel = new Label("Font:");
    Label fontStyleLabel = new Label("Font Style:");
    Label fontSizeLabel = new Label("Font Size: ");

    // Add font list view
    ListView<String> fontView = new ListView<>();
    String fonts[] = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().getAvailableFontFamilyNames();
    for (int i = 0; i < fonts.length; i++) {
        fontView.getItems().add(fonts[i]);
    }
    fontView.getSelectionModel().select(fontFamily);
    fontView.setMaxSize(200, 150);
    fontView.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener((v) -> {
        fontFamily = fontView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();
        sample.setStyle(getCSS());
    });

    // Add font style list view
    ListView<String> fontStyleView = new ListView<>();
    fontStyleView.getItems().addAll("Regular", "Italic", "Bold", "Bold Italic");
    fontStyleView.getSelectionModel().select(savedStyle);
    fontStyleView.setMaxSize(80, 150);
    fontStyleView.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener((v) -> {
        fontStyle = getChosenStyle(fontStyleView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem());
        fontWeight = getChosenWeight(fontStyleView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem());
        sample.setStyle(getCSS());
    });

    // Add font size list view
    ListView<String> fontSizeView = new ListView<>();
    fontSizeView.getItems().addAll("6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "14", "16", "18", "20", "22", "24", "26", "28");
    fontSizeView.getSelectionModel().select(fontSize);
    fontSizeView.setMaxSize(80, 150);
    fontSizeView.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener((v) -> {
        fontSize = fontSizeView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();
        sample.setStyle(getCSS());
    });

    // Add OK button
    Button okButton = new Button("OK");
    okButton.setOnAction(e -> {
        fontCssString = getCSS();
        window.close();
    });

    // Add cancel button
    Button cancelButton = new Button("Cancel");
    cancelButton.setOnAction(e -> {
        window.close();
    });

    // Add and configure grid pane
    GridPane layout = new GridPane();
    layout.setPadding(new Insets(15, 15, 15, 15));
    layout.setVgap(20);
    layout.setHgap(20);

    // Set grid constraints for font list view and title
    GridPane.setConstraints(fontLabel, 0, 0);
    GridPane.setConstraints(fontView, 0, 1);

    // Set grid constraints for font style list view and title
    GridPane.setConstraints(fontStyleLabel, 1, 0);
    GridPane.setConstraints(fontStyleView, 1, 1);
    GridPane.setValignment(fontStyleView, VPos.TOP);

    // Set grid constraints for font size list view and title
    GridPane.setConstraints(fontSizeLabel, 2, 0);
    GridPane.setConstraints(fontSizeView, 2, 1);

    // Set grid constraints for sample title
    GridPane.setConstraints(sample, 0, 2);
    GridPane.setHalignment(sample, HPos.CENTER);

    // set grid constraints and alignments for buttons
    GridPane.setConstraints(okButton, 1, 2);
    GridPane.setHalignment(okButton, HPos.RIGHT);
    GridPane.setConstraints(cancelButton, 2, 2);

    // Add items to grid pane layout
    layout.getChildren().addAll(fontLabel, fontView, fontStyleLabel, fontStyleView, fontSizeLabel, fontSizeView,
            sample, okButton, cancelButton);

    // configure the scene and stage
    Scene scene = new Scene(layout, 450, 300);
    scene.getStylesheets().add(FontWindow.class.getResource(stylesheet).toExternalForm());
    window.setScene(scene);
    window.setTitle("Font Options");
    window.showAndWait();

    return fontCssString;
}

public static final String getChosenStyle(String s) {
    String result = "normal";
    if (s.contains("Italic")) {
        result = "italic";
    }
    return result;
}

public static final String getChosenWeight(String s) {
    String result = "normal";
    if (s.contains("Bold")) {
        result = "bold";
    }
    return result;
}

public static String getCSS() {
    return "-fx-font-family: " + fontFamily + "; -fx-font-weight: " + fontWeight + "; -fx-font-style: " + fontStyle
            + "; -fx-font-size: " + Float.valueOf(fontSize) / 9.7 + "em;";
}
}
```

Edit: This has been solved! I was able to get the text field to function as I wanted by setting the maximum and minimum size as well as setting the preferred height and width to 'region.USE_COMPUTED_SIZE'.

Comment: If @zlakad's answer helped you solve your problem, please accept it as correct.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This woks to me.

```
<TextField layoutX="151.0" layoutY="53.0" maxHeight="50.0" maxWidth="255.0" minHeight="50.0" minWidth="255.0" text="AaZz">
```

...and Pref Height/Pref Width are "USE_COMPUTED_SIZE"

Comment: Thank you for your response. Is there any way of implementing this without using FXML?

Comment: Try this methods: `txtF.setMaxSize(50, 200);
        txtF.setMinSize(50, 200);` where txtF is your TextField

Comment: oops, the first argument is Width, the second one is Height. And remove PrefSize. Tell me if it works. Good Luck.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Your solution (combining setMinSize, setMaxSize, & USE_COMPUTED_SIZE for pref height and width) worked :)

Answer (score 1):

All `TextField` has preferred padding in each side.

Tips: to change the `TextField` into the least size, make it sure change also the padding of the `TextField` to make the size you want.

in JavaFx:

```
TextField textDisplay = new TextField();
textDisplay.setPrefSize(100,5);
textDisplay.setPadding(new Insets(1,1,1,1));
```

if you want set the size of your textField base on the fontSize in textField ,just leave it a null "DONT USE" `.setPrefSize(double,double);` that will set the static size of your textField BUT set the max of your textfield using css/javafx

```
textDisplay.setMaxWidth(double);
textDisplay.setMaxHeiht(double);
```

or

```
textDisplay.setSize(double,double);
```

but if you use CSS much more easy to design your GUI just dont forget set an ID of your nodes.

```
textDisplay.setStyle("-fx-pref-width: 100"
                  +"\n-fx-pref-height: 100"
                    +"-fx-padding: 5 5 5 5;");
```

or

```
textDisplay.setId("idTextDisplay");
#idTextDisplay{
  -fx-pref-width: 100;
  -fx-pref-height: 100;
  -fx-padding: 5 5 5 5;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in your case is:

```
TextField sample = new TextField("AaBbYyZz");
    sample.setEditable(false);
    sample.getStyleClass().add("sample");
    sample.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
    sample.setStyle(getCSS());
    sample.setPrefSize(200, 60);
    sample.prefHeight(Region.USE_COMPUTED_SIZE);
    sample.prefwidth(Region.USE_COMPUTED_SIZE);
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I have tried implementing your code and I'm afraid it hasn't worked.

Comment: update. I got it working by adding setMinHeight and setMaxHeight. Thank you for your help :)

Comment: Correction: setMinSize and setMaxSize